# Multiple pages running same polling script

Tags: php, jquery, database, polling

I have a jQuery script in my header that updates the last_active datetime database field every 60 seconds. The problem is, if the user has multiple windows open then this puts extra pressure on the server as each page is updating after 60 seconds.

I would rather fix this problem without having to resort to frames... if that's even possible.

Any way around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can check which IP requests are coming from in your PHP logic, and place a condition that only performs the update from that IP if it has not already been done in the past 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys... To be honest, its a very simple SQL query. Just updates the database with the current datetime. Logging IPs and calculating the time since the last query seems like more work. I was hoping to implement something at the client-side through javascript that would detect the number of page instances and only run the update script on one of them...

Answer (score 0):

You can do as Will suggested but the problem in the above case is, not all the users use public ip to browse the InterNet. In this case you can try to check the browser version and session ID also with the IP. Then you can even different statistics for the users behind the ISP/Cyber Cafe's with single IP and multiple browsing machines.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you keep such a field? Is it not possible to just maintain the "last_accessed" time whenever a request comes in and use that for your purposes rather than something like what you're doing?

Comment: I am building a site that tracks what users are online at any given time. The script will update the database every 60 seconds if the page is still open (ie. they are still online). Guess I could store the last update time in the users session rather than the database and determine at the client-side if an update is required :)

Comment: When people login, you store the "last_accessed" time with an expiry *on the server*. At every request, you update this field. Whenever you're calculating number of users, you simply run through this table and find ones that have not expired and print them. Would that not work?